# Casting with conditional/ternary ("?:") operator

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have this extract of C# source code:

```
object valueFromDatabase;
decimal result;
valueFromDatabase = DBNull.Value;

result = (decimal)(valueFromDatabase != DBNull.Value ? valueFromDatabase : 0);
result = (valueFromDatabase != DBNull.Value ? (decimal)valueFromDatabase : (decimal)0);
```

The first result evaluation throws an `InvalidCastException` whereas the second one does not.
What is the difference between these two?

Comment: I want to clarify that in the first ones evaluates to zero and not to DBNull.value. Why casting 0 to decimal throws an exception?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog on May 27th 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/cast-operators-do-not-obey-the-distributive-law). Thanks for the great question!

There are a great many very confusing answers here.  Let me try to precisely answer your question. Let's simplify this down:

```
object value = whatever;
bool condition = something;
decimal result = (decimal)(condition ? value : 0);
```

How does the compiler interpret the last line?  The problem faced by the compiler is that the **type of the conditional expression must be consistent for both branches**; the language rules do not allow you to return object on one branch and int on the other. The choices are object and int. Every int is convertible to object but not every object is convertible to int, so the compiler chooses object. Therefore this is the same as

```
decimal result = (decimal)(condition ? (object)value : (object)0);
```

Therefore the zero returned is a boxed int.

You then unbox the int to decimal. It is illegal to unbox a boxed int to decimal. For the reasons why, see my blog article on that subject:

[Representation and Identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

Basically, your problem is that you're acting as though the cast to decimal were distributed, like this:

```
decimal result = condition ? (decimal)value : (decimal)0;
```

But as we've seen, that is not what

```
decimal result = (decimal)(condition ? value : 0);
```

means. That means "make both alternatives into objects and then unbox the resulting object".

Comment: I don't understand why compiler is inserting type conversions where compilation error seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: @raj: What rule would you like to see implemented to determine when to give a compilation error?

Comment: I believe Compiler should have told me this rule "the language rules do not allow you to return object on one branch and int on the other" instead of casting int to object to make itself happy. Loannis would have found the problem with the statement had compiler told him what's wrong with it

Comment: @Raj: OK, then what should the compiler do with b ? "" : null - that returns a string on one branch and a typeless null reference on the other. Should the compiler complain about that? Since one side doesn't even have a type, clearly the types are not equal.

Comment: You could easily make the compiler rule be that "You can't return different types on each branch unless one of them is typeless". But a more fundamental problem is that you might want to do something like `b ? DoX() : DoY()` with no assignment at all.  If DoX() and DoY() have different return types, it shouldn't matter; you shouldn't have to cast a value that you're discarding.  I don't think it would be feasible to make the compiler rule become "You can't return different types on each branch unless one of them is typeless or the result is not used."  I assume it would not be worth the time.

Comment: @Matthew: How would you make a legal C# program with a conditional expression such that the value is not used?

Comment: @Eric A familiar error message "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize it couldn't be used without assignment. [This C# Reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) doesn't say anything about it.  "You can express calculations that might otherwise require an if-else construction more concisely by using the conditional operator" in particular seems like it needs to say "some calculations", since I apparently cannot replace `if(b) X(); else Y();` with `b ? X() : Y();`.

Comment: Anyways, then: Since you can't use a conditional without assignment, the rule **could** be "You can't return different types on each branch unless one of them is typeless."  Presumably I'm still missing a reason why it would be infeasible or clash with existing rules.

Comment: @Matthew: We can't change it now because that would be a breaking change. People rely on the current behaviour. But even if we could, it seems too strict. Do you really want the compiler to give an error when the consequence is of type Animal and the alternative is Giraffe?

Comment: Not at all, it was more for the sake of argument and curiosity.  Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that the compiler can not determine a data type that is a good match between `Object` and `Int32`.

You can explicitly cast the `int` value to `object` to get the same data type in the second and third operand so that it compiles, but that of couse means that you are boxing and unboxing the value:

```
result = (decimal)(valueFromDatabase != DBNull.value ? valueFromDatabase : (object)0);
```

That will compile, but not run. You have to box a decimal value to unbox as a decimal value:

```
result = (decimal)(valueFromDatabase != DBNull.value ? valueFromDatabase : (object)0M);
```

Comment: C# Specification:
"A boxing conversion permits a value-type to be implicitly converted to a reference type. A boxing conversion 
exists from any non-nullable-value-type to object, to System.ValueType and to any interface-type 
implemented by the non-nullable-value-type. Furthermore an enum-type can be converted to the type 
System.Enum. "

So there is implicit boxing conversion between Int32 and object.

If the compiler could not determine the type it would fail at compile time and not at runtime.

Please see my answer...

Answer (score 5):

The type of the operator will be object and in case the result must be 0 it will be implicitly boxed. But 0 literal is by default has int type so you box int. But with explicit cast to decimal you try to unbox it which is not permitted (boxed type must much with the one you cast back to). That is why you can get exception.

Here is an excerpt from C# Specification:

The second and third operands of the ?: operator control the type of the conditional expression. Let X and Y be the types of the second and third operands. Then,

- If X and Y are the same type, then this is the type of the conditional expression.
- Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the 
  conditional expression.
- Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from Y to X, but not from X to Y, then X is the type of the 
  conditional expression.
- Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Your line should be:

```
result = valueFromDatabase != DBNull.value ? (decimal)valueFromDatabase : 0m;
```

**0m** is the decimal constant for zero

Both parts of a conditional operator should evaluate to the same data type

Comment: That will most likely compile into exactly the same code as the second line.

Comment: maybe, but it's worth pointing out what the decimal constant for zero is

Answer (score 3):

The x : y part need a common type, the database's value is likely some kind of float and 0 is an int. This happens before the cast to decimal. Try ": 0.0" or ": 0D".

Comment: What the value from the database actually is has no relevance for the compiler. The type of the variable is Object, and a Double value will not match better than an Int32 value.

Comment: As others have said, it is 0m

Comment: Literal zero of type decimal: 0m.

Comment: This is not a compiler error, it is a run time error. Databases normally return decimal values as doubles so that is the type you are trying to match.

Comment: However, if the runtime type is decimal then go ahead and use M. :)

Comment: @ongle: If a database returns a Decimal value as a Double it is a serious error, as you will lose precision.

Comment: @Guffa: Decimal is the c# type, not the DB type. We don't know what the DB type is (Decimal in SQL Server means something else with a  definable precision). The key here is that this is a run time error, what matters is the run time type of the value in valueFromDatabase. Whatever type that is is the type that needs to be matched or special casting should be employed to make the values type compatible (The solution your answer takes). I'm betting it is a double.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken (which is very possible) its actually the 0 that's causing the exception, and this is down to .NET (crazily) assuming the type of a literal so you need to specify 0m rather than just 0.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.80).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types for the compiler to decide (at compile time) which one to cast to decimal. This it can't do.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer would work if you combined both:

```
result = (decimal)(valueFromDatabase != DBNull.Value ? (decimal)valueFromDatabase : (decimal)0);
```

At least, a similar situation casting into a parameter for me.

Comment: This makes no sense: since you cast both the branches, the initial cast is useless.