# Why use (int?) null when adopt object initializer?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class User
    {
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public int? ID { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.Age = null;        // no warning or error
            user.ID  = (int?)null;  // no warning or error

            string result = string.Empty;
            User user2 = new User
                             {
                Age = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? null : Int32.Parse(result),
                // Error    1   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined 
                // because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int'   
                // ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   23  71  ConsoleApplication1

                ID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? (int?)null : Int32.Parse(result) // // no warning or error
                             };
        }
    }
}
```

Question:

Why the following line doesn't work?

```
Age = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? null : Int32.Parse(result)
```

// Correction one is

```
Age = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? (int?) null : Int32.Parse(result)
```

Why the following line work?

```
user.Age = null;        // no warning or error
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171717

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Age = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? null : Int32.Parse(result)
```

Doesn't work because the `string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? null : Int32.Parse(result)` is evaluated separately from the `Age =` part.

The compiler can't figure out what type `string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? null : Int32.Parse(result)` is supposed to be.

It first sees `null` which indicates that it's a reference type, and it sees an `int` which is a value type which seems incompatible.  The fact that there exists a type with an implicit cast operator from `int` to `int?` isn't inferred by the compiler.

It could in theory have enough information to figure it out but the compiler would need to be a lot more sophisticated.

Answer (score 6):

Its because the ternary operator needs the return types to be the same type.

In the 1st case "null" could be a null of any reference type (not just int?) so to make it explicit to the compiler it needs casting.

Otherwise you could have

```
string x = null;
Age = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? x: Int32.Parse(result)
```

which is obviously a bit cuckooo.

Answer (score 2):

Because C# enforces that every expression must have a type. The compiler is unable to determine the type of the ternary expression in the non-working line.

Answer (score 2):

The `? :` inline if operator does not know which type to return because the two arguments are `null` and `int`.  Since `int` cannot ever be null, the compiler cannot resolve the type returned by `?:`.