# What is the difference between these 2 statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# ?: Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171717/c-sharp-conditional-operator)

---

statement first:

```
if(dr["AskingPriceFrom"]!=System.DBNull.Value) 
    objFilters.AskingPriceFrom=Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AskingPriceFrom"]);
else 
    objFilters.AskingPriceFrom=null;
```

statement second:

```
objFilters.AskingPriceFrom=Convert.ToDecimal(
    dr["AskingPriceFrom"]!=System.DBNull.Value ? dr["AskingPriceFrom"] : null
    );
```

**What is difference between these two statements?**

In first statement, if value is empty in *if-else* condition, then it stores *null* value correctly; but, if value is empty in the second condition, then instead of storing *null* value it stores `0`. `AskingPriceFrom` is a get-set field stores *decimal* value. I tried to convert only `dr["AskingPriceFrom"]` after the question mark but the statement gives me an error.

**Is there any way to protect *null* value from converting in *decimal*?**

Comment: Functionally, nothing different.

Comment: In your second statement, you are doing a convert to decimal of `null` which returns a 0. You should move the convert statement inside.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ?: Conditional Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171717/c-sharp-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen. This is working properly.

```
objFilters.AskingPriceFrom = dr["AskingPriceFrom"] != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AskingPriceFrom"]) : (decimal?)null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `Convert.ToDecimal(null) == 0`

//Edit: This should work

```
objFilters.AskingPriceFrom =  
      (dr["AskingPriceFrom"] != System.DBNull.Value) ? 
       Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AskingPriceFrom"]) : null;
```

Comment: Error."Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'decimal' and 'bool'"

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'decimal' and '<null>'

Comment: That type can't be null. As dutzu says, you have to either change the type or make it 0

Comment: If decimal type cant be null than how it store NULL value in first statement? Its working correctly with same type. I think in second statement we need to avoid conversion of null into decimal. Is it possible?..

Comment: I can assure you the first statement didn't work either with null. I actually can't even get it to compile. Are you sure it's a decimal?

Comment: The conditional operator `b ? x : y` needs to find a best common type for `x` and `y`. Help it by casting either `x` or `y` to `(decimal?)`.

Comment: @Suraj To repeat myself, hcb's solution is right, except he has to qualify for the type of the `?:` expression to be inferred. This will work: `objFilters.AskingPriceFrom = dr["AskingPriceFrom"] != System.DBNull.Value ? (decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AskingPriceFrom"]) : null;`. Also this will work: `objFilters.AskingPriceFrom = dr["AskingPriceFrom"] != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AskingPriceFrom"]) : (decimal?)null;`

Comment: @Suraj See [Nullable types and the ternary operator: why is `? 10 : null` forbidden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/) for the explanation of why hcb's answer needed this twist.

Comment: Good to know!! Nice information!!@Jeppe Stig Nielse and @hcb's thanks for help!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because Decimal is not nullable. You should cast to `decimal?` so that when you convert a null to that type it will not return the default value 0 but instead return null.

Comment: If value is empty.It should have to store NULL not 0.

Comment: @Suraj no, because decimal is a value type not a reference type and therefore cannot be null. But if you declare it as `decimal?` it will become in fact a `Nullable<decimal>` which is a reference type and can have a null value.

Answer (score 0):

in the inline version(*ternary*)
if it is **null** you will get:

```
objFilters.AskingPriceFrom =  Convert.ToDecimal(null);
```

this will probably result an error.

Comment: No, it gives zero (`0m`) of type `decimal` which is then wrapped to a nullable decimal that `HasValue` (namely that zero).

Comment: you are right, for Convert.ToDecimal(object) return value, microsoft had said: A decimal number that is equivalent to value, or 0 (zero) if value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should read `Convert.ToDecimal` documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6440ed8.aspx.

`Convert.ToDecimal` returns `decimal` or throws exception, but in your case you need return type as `Nullable<decimal>`.

You can use code like this:

```
decimal? result;
if (Convert.IsDBNull(dr["AskingPriceFrom"]))
{
   result= null;
}
else
{
   result = dr.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("AskingPriceFrom"));
}
```